# Find All Numbers Disappeared in an Array (Getting IndexOutOFBoundsException

Tags: java

I keep getting a IndexOutOFBoundsException and i cant seem to find where. Ive spent ages trying to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
class Solution {

public List<Integer> findDisappearedNumbers(int[] nums) {

    if(nums.length < 2){
        return new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<Integer>(nums.length);

    for(int i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
        ret.set(i,i);
    }

    for(int i=0; i < nums.length; i++){            
        ret.set(nums[i]-1, nums[i]);
    }     

    for(int i=0; i < nums.length; i++){ 
        if(ret.get(i) == 0){
            ret.set(i, i+1);
        }
        else{
            ret.remove(i);
        }
    }
    return ret;       
}
```

}

Comment: What should this code do? Because we don't know what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: You aren't adding anything to your list `ret`, that's why it's throwing an exception when you try to access an element inside of it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Given an array of integers where 1 ≤ a[i] ≤ n (n = size of array), some elements appear twice and others appear once.

Find all the elements of [1, n] inclusive that do not appear in this array.

Comment: @Schred for(int i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
        ret.set(i,i);
    }

Comment: @Schred i thought this code sets all the elements inside to 0?

Comment: I would start by sorting the array. Then you can scan from left to right and look for gaps.

Comment: @D-odu There are no elements inside the list you could set to 0. If you want to do that, use `ret.add(0); ` inside that loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i < nums.length; i++){            
    ret.set(nums[i]-1, nums[i]);
}
```

There you set the `nums[i]-1`s index to `nums[i]` but it will throw the error if `nums[i]` is either smaller or equal to `0` or higher than the length.

As the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60959574/10871900) from @[Bahij.Mik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9264713/bahij-mik) states(make sure to upvote it), there are no elements in the list at this point.

You may want to use `add()` instead of `set()` here.

Note that `new ArrayList<>(number)` will create a new `ArrayList` with an initial **space** for `n` elements, it will not fill the elements like it would happen with an array(not even with null)

Also, in

```
for(int i=0; i < nums.length; i++){ 
    if(ret.get(i) == 0){
        ret.set(i, i+1);
    }
    else{
        ret.remove(i);
    }
}
```

you are removing elements while iterating over the `ArrayList`.

This will reduce the size of the `ArrayList` and you will iterate out of the bounds if you removed an element at some point.

Comment: I see. My entire solution to this problem was flawed. Thank you for pointing out the iterating out of bounds point, I understand

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your code, first thing that comes to sight is that when you are instantiating your arraylist with

```
List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<Integer>(nums.length);
```

You are just setting the list's initial capacity not the size, so you can't set elements at specific indices, instead you need to add elements to the list then you can modify them at said indices, so instead of the `ret.set(i, i)` use `ret.add(i)`.

Comment: ahhh. i see. I assumed set would do the same job as add. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
class Solution {

public List<Integer> findDisappearedNumbers(int[] nums) {

    List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        int index = Math.abs(nums[i]) - 1;
        if(nums[index] > 0 ){
            nums[index] *= -1;
        }
    }

    for(int j = 1; j <= nums.length; j++){
        if(nums[j-1] > 0 ){
            ret.add(j);
        }
    }
    return ret;

}
```

}